# How do I change the color of particles with a color ramp?

Tags: particles

I watched this tutorial https://youtu.be/eshOzshjt90 and at [2:18](https://youtu.be/eshOzshjt90?t=138) he somehow magically managed to get a different color on his second particle via the color ramp. But the color ramp doesn't do anything at all? I'm really confused. How do I change or invert the color of my second particle?

Answer (score 2):

If your particle system is instancing an object then you can customise the particles to sample random colours by using this node setup on your instancing object:

[image]

Here, all I've done is use the random output of an object info node with a colour ramp :)

Comment: mhh, thats not really what I'm searching for :/ my plane has two hair particles, the second one is a duplicate of the first one. The first particle should have color a and the second one color b... i tried with creating a texture and enable color ramp, but color ramp doesn't do anything...